# Advice for college freshman?

Tags: education

This is my first time posting on a Quant forum (or StackExchange in general), so bear with me. It might be the wrong place to post.

I am a rising senior and I plan on majoring in finance and computer science in college. In my free time I have developed financial apps in Java (portfolio optimization using MPT, backtesting etc) but on this Quant forum there is plenty of math and models I dont know. I know a lot of the terms that are mentioned, so the vocabulary I understand (options, call, put, volatility, etc).

How do you suggest I get more involved with the math associated with this field? Math hasnt been my strongest field, but I want to learn these things. How do I start? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi user1222, welcome to Quant.SE! As your in college, a good way would of course be to take some courses or do an interesting internship. Another good way to learn would be answer questions here, a good amount of questions are answerable by doing some research and thinking but don't require mathematical prowess. However, since it's hard to give hard to give good, generally useful answers to questions like these, career advice is not on-topic here so I've closed it.

Comment: @BobJansen Alright thank you for the advice!